# View Client Certificate in HTTPS request in Fiddler4

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, fiddler

Whilst troubleshooting a production issue I'm trying to assert that an SSL web request I fire contains a certificate. We add the certificate to the request, but I would like to view the used certificate in Fiddler in the way I *do* see the certificate used by the server in the response using HTTPS decryption.

A test project fires a request to `https://google.com` and Fiddler reveals the server certificate (in the *Raw* response):

```
== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=www.google.com, O=Google LLC, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=GTS CA 1O1, O=Google Trust Services, C=US

[Serial Number]
  00ED7F80A1379302560800000000190DCD

[Not Before]
  10/10/2019 22:56:23

[Not After]
  02/01/2020 21:56:23

[Thumbprint]
  5497AE80F516A69148B091D39E01A427835FB0FC
```

But no info like this on the request certificate can be found.

Does anyone know if and where info like this can be found for the request?

This is the code I use to fire the request, pointing to a self generated certificate for which I have the password:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(
            fileName: "D:\\temp\\powershellcert.pfx",
            password: "password1234",
            keyStorageFlags: X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
        Request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        Request.UserAgent = "Client Cert Sample";
        Request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I am not sure if Fiddler at all sends the request for the client certificate to the client (the server can explicitly ask the client in the TLS handshake to present a matching client certificate). IMHO you should better use Wireshark as it does not modify the request as a proxy like Fiddler does. In SSL/TLS the server and client certificates are exchanged before the encrypted channel starts, therefore you can see them in a simple Wireshark dump.

Comment: @Aage, just wondering if you found the solution for this?

Comment: @CHash11 Don't think I have, otherwise I would've answered it probably (-: